# How to work with files above server root directory in a website

Tags: html, css, apache, server

I have configured an apache server with document root to public_html folder and i want to keep my  css files in the above directory as following code

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login_page.css">
</head>
```

Using above code i am not getting style changes related to css but if i keep my css file in public_html folder and change it to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_page.css">
```

there seems no problem. I want to know how to make the first code work.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot reference files, folders outside your `public_html` folder. Hence the name of the folder. It's by design and it would be a **BIG** security risk if this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about cache? Have you tried clear cahce and reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seams impossible, the apache server can only send the file in your `public_html`.(for security reasons)
More that the server side, your browser will request a file that it's not in the domain.

The only solution it's to be in your `public_html`.

Edit:
The only files that you work with were are above are php files of config files, apache will never work with files that are above the `public_html`

Comment: So i can only use php to access files that are above

Comment: yes, but a css file no because browser ask directly the to the apache server not the ndex.php file.

Comment: but i'm thinking of a solution very bad solution ... your php can get all the css and put it directly into the html, you will not have to write this line ` <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login_page.css">` . But it's not a solution good solution. The best solution stay do let the css file in the `public` folder

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear enough for me, but if your problem is that css file in browser doesn't update when you edit it, the solution is to disable cache for your site 
In any browser: devtools -> network -> disable cache checkbox 
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMA6k.png)

Comment: Nice conditional answer, a good tool while you do not have the commenting privilege. "If the problem is .. then the solution is to ...".

Comment: I want to use files that are above server root in html

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not impossible or hard to do because of security risks. Imagine anyone can browse files stored on your server